# Js file doesn't work when imported in Angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've used an HTML template in my angular project. Everything seems fine until I realized that some js files doesn't work which affected the whole project. The most important part is even the main.js file didn't work. My lect said to ignore the js and recreate which part doesn't work but I'm tryna use this file because there are many things in there.

Here are the codes in the main.js file, is there something here that is not compatible with Angular?

This is my first time using StackOverflow so I'm sorry if there's anything wrong with the way I'm asking

````
(function () {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Easy selector helper function
   */
  const select = (el, all = false) => {
    el = el.trim()
    if (all) {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)]
    } else {
      return document.querySelector(el)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy event listener function
   */
  const on = (type, el, listener, all = false) => {
    let selectEl = select(el, all)
    if (selectEl) {
      if (all) {
        selectEl.forEach(e => e.addEventListener(type, listener))
      } else {
        selectEl.addEventListener(type, listener)
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy on scroll event listener 
   */
  const onscroll = (el, listener) => {
    el.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
  }

  /**
   * Navbar links active state on scroll
   */
  let navbarlinks = select('#navbar .scrollto', true)
  const navbarlinksActive = () => {
    let position = window.scrollY + 200
    navbarlinks.forEach(navbarlink => {
      if (!navbarlink.hash) return
      let section = select(navbarlink.hash)
      if (!section) return
      if (position >= section.offsetTop && position <= (section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight)) {
        navbarlink.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        navbarlink.classList.remove('active')
      }
    })
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', navbarlinksActive)
  onscroll(document, navbarlinksActive)

  /**
   * Scrolls to an element with header offset
   */
  const scrollto = (el) => {
    let header = select('#header')
    let offset = header.offsetHeight

    let elementPos = select(el).offsetTop
    window.scrollTo({
      top: elementPos - offset,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })
  }

  /**
   * Toggle .header-scrolled class to #header when page is scrolled
   */
  let selectHeader = select('#header')
  if (selectHeader) {
    const headerScrolled = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        selectHeader.classList.add('header-scrolled')
      } else {
        selectHeader.classList.remove('header-scrolled')
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', headerScrolled)
    onscroll(document, headerScrolled)
  }

  /**
   * Back to top button
   */
  let backtotop = select('.back-to-top')
  if (backtotop) {
    const toggleBacktotop = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        backtotop.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        backtotop.classList.remove('active')
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', toggleBacktotop)
    onscroll(document, toggleBacktotop)
  }

  /**
   * Mobile nav toggle
   */
  on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
    select('#navbar').classList.toggle('navbar-mobile')
    this.classList.toggle('bi-list')
    this.classList.toggle('bi-x')
  })

  /**
   * Mobile nav dropdowns activate
   */
  on('click', '.navbar .dropdown > a', function(e) {
    if (select('#navbar').classList.contains('navbar-mobile')) {
      e.preventDefault()
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('dropdown-active')
    }
  }, true)

  /**
   * Scrool with ofset on links with a class name .scrollto
   */
  on('click', '.scrollto', function(e) {
    if (select(this.hash)) {
      e.preventDefault()

      let navbar = select('#navbar')
      if (navbar.classList.contains('navbar-mobile')) {
        navbar.classList.remove('navbar-mobile')
        let navbarToggle = select('.mobile-nav-toggle')
        navbarToggle.classList.toggle('bi-list')
        navbarToggle.classList.toggle('bi-x')
      }
      scrollto(this.hash)
    }
  }, true)

  /**
   * Scroll with ofset on page load with hash links in the url
   */
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      if (select(window.location.hash)) {
        scrollto(window.location.hash)
      }
    }
  });

  /**
   * Preloader
   */
  let preloader = select('#preloader');
  if (preloader) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      preloader.remove()
    });
  }

  /**
   * Clients Slider
   */
  new Swiper('.clients-slider', {
    speed: 400,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
      clickable: true
    },
    breakpoints: {
      320: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 40
      },
      480: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 60
      },
      640: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 80
      },
      992: {
        slidesPerView: 6,
        spaceBetween: 120
      }
    }
  });

  /**
   * Porfolio isotope and filter
   */
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
    if (portfolioContainer) {
      let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
      });

      let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);

      on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('filter-active');
        });
        this.classList.add('filter-active');

        portfolioIsotope.arrange({
          filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
        });
        portfolioIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
          AOS.refresh()
        });
      }, true);
    }

  });

  /**
   * Initiate portfolio lightbox 
   */
  const portfolioLightbox = GLightbox({
    selector: '.portfolio-lightbox'
  });

  /**
   * Portfolio details slider
   */
  new Swiper('.portfolio-details-slider', {
    speed: 400,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
      clickable: true
    }
  });

  /**
   * Testimonials slider
   */
  new Swiper('.testimonials-slider', {
    speed: 600,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
      clickable: true
    }
  });

  /**
   * Animation on scroll
   */
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "ease-in-out",
      once: true,
      mirror: false
    });
  });

})()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to export this code logic, and import it in the files that you need it in.

Let's put all your code in a file called a.js.

Your file becomes

```
export default a = (function () {
  "use strict";

...
```

let's create a file called b.js on the same level as a.js
And later you import it in b.js as follows

```
import a from "./a"
```

###### Note

Once you import a.js into any file, all the logic inside it will be automatically executed (you can see the function execution at the end) because the function self executes.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, but I accidentally added $ before ```(function()``` and it suddenly works. But still, there's an error saying ```main.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:8```

Comment: @dee you need to rename the package to whatever you'd like to have it be named.
So in your case, you seem to want to $ symbol for JQuery, so instead of:
`export default a`, you should write `export default $` and import it in the other file.